# add extra class when click on list item, on basis of data-pos name?

Tags: javascript

```
  <ul id="myList">
      <li class="list" data-pos="Noah">pass</li>
      <li class="list" data-pos="Liam">fail</li>
      <li class="list" data-pos="James">average</li>
   </ul>
```

Now I want to create a JavaScript function that will add new class, when click on it.

```
   click (data-pos="Noah")  add class Noah1
   click (data-pos="Liam")  add class Liam1
   click (data-pos="James") add class James1
```

Expected Result After Click

```
 <ul id="myList">
     <li class="list Noah1"   data-pos="Noah">pass</li>
     <li class="list Liam1"  data-pos="Liam">fail</li>
     <li class="list James1" data-pos="James">average</li>
 </ul>
```

How can I do that? with JavaScript

Comment: What have you tried ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is working solution, just get `data-pos` attribute and add it to `classList`

```js
function clickEvent(event) {
  event.target.classList.add(event.target.getAttribute('data-pos') + "1")
  console.log(event.target.classList)
}

document.querySelector('ul').addEventListener('click', clickEvent, false);
```

```html
<ul class="myList">
     <li class="list" data-pos="Noah">pass</li>
     <li class="list" data-pos="Liam">fail</li>
     <li class="list" data-pos="James">average</li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Sir We Are Update Some HTML On This Code And Solve With Help of Basis This Answer. Codepen Link [https://codepen.io/MrUmang/pen/LYbVgoX]   Stackoverflow Link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66014256/want-to-add-a-css-class-to-an-element-when-it-is-clicked] And Thanks again for your answer

Answer (score 2):

```
var changeFunc -> (e) {

 document.getElementById(...).classList.add((this.querySelector(":selected").getAttribute("data-pos") + "1"));

}

document.querySelector(".myList").addEventListener("change",changeFunc);
```

Answer (score 1):

One-liner solution:

```
document.querySelectorAll('ul>li.list').forEach(li=>{li.onclick=function(){const attr=li.getAttribute('data-pos');if(!(attr in li.classList))li.classList.add(attr);}});
```