# Want to add a CSS class to an element when it is clicked

Tags: javascript

Given this HTML:

```
 <ul class="myList">
   <li class="List" data-pos="Noah">
      <label><input class="text">pass</label>
   </li>
   <li class="List" data-pos="Liam">
      <label><input class="text">fail</label>
   </li>
   <li class="List" data-pos="James">
      <label><input class="text">average</label>
  </li>
 </ul>
```

I want to create a JavaScript function that will add new class to an element when the user clicks on it, based on the `data-pos` attribute of the element.

```
   click on "Noah"  add class Noah1
   click on "Liam"  add class Liam1
   click on "James" add class James1
```

Expected result after clicking all the elements:

```
 <ul class="myList">
   <li class="List Noah1" data-pos="Noah">
       <label><input class="text">pass</label>
   </li>
   <li class="List Liam1" data-pos="Liam">
       <label><input class="text">fail</label>
   </li>
   <li class="List James1" data-pos="James">
       <label><input class="text">average</label>
   </li>
 </ul>
```

I tried the following javascript. It results in `<label class="null1">` instead of `<li class="List Noah1">` or `<li class="List Liam1">` or `<li class="List James1">`

```
function clickEvent(event) {
    event.target.classList.add(event.target.getAttribute('data-pos') + "1")
    console.log(event.target.classList)
}

document.querySelector('ul').addEventListener('click', clickEvent, false);
```

Comment: Put `const target = event.target.closest('li');` at the beginning of the click handler, and use `target` instead of `event.target` in the later code. Notice also, that you've to remove the harcoded "name classes". This way you can click what ever element inside a list element, and the code will find the closest list element in the parent chain. It's also good to check, that `target` was actually found, otherwise the code will trigger an error, if you've somehow managed to click outside of an list element but still inside the ul.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have nested elements. The click event fires on the inner element (`label`) and then bubbles up to the `ul` element.

You need to step to the parent element if the `label` receives the click.

```
function clickEvent(event) {
  let element = event.target
  if(element.tagName === 'LABEL') {
    element = event.target.parentElement;
  }
  element.classList.add(element.getAttribute('data-pos') + "1")
  console.log(element.classList)
}
```

Comment: Sir it is working perfect but it is also add  unnecessary `<input class="text null1">`  we are add in codepen to this please reply [https://codepen.io/MrUmang/pen/WNoQvvq] And this javascript code working 1st row only, after 1st row it is not working on 2nd, 3rd. 4th,... row please how can solve this problem @randy casburn

Comment: Sorry For That Link url https://codepen.io/MrUmang/pen/WNoQvvq @randy casburn

Comment: **Still a 404**. I will tell you that the reason you receive `null1` as a class name is because this code: `element.getAttribute('data-pos`)` returns `null`. That means that LI does not have an attribute named `data-pos`. it would be best to use the [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset) API for accessing the `data-` attributes anyway. Try that in place of `.getAttribute()`. To use `dataset` change `element.getAttribute('data-pos`)` to `element.dataset.pos`.